# Is it possible to (naturally) integrate an algebraic curve into quantum computers?

Tags: algebraic-curves, quantum-computation

A projective algebraic curve is defined over an projective space as zeros of some homogeneous polynomial. While quantum computers almost canonically holds their states in a "ket," i.e. a vector in the projective space.

Let's say I have defined an Elliptic curve with $$f=x^3+ax+b-y^2, F=z^{\deg{f}} f(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}),$$ rational points are stored within a ket $$|Q\rangle,|P\rangle=\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}\in\mathbb{P_2(C)}, F(x,y,z)=0,$$ and what if I would like to support point arithmetic gate $+$ that somehow allows $+(|P\rangle|Q\rangle|0\rangle)=|P+Q\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle$, this is quite likely to be non-linear so perhaps adding up some dimension would be necessary.

Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in simple words what do you mean? Do you want to make a QC memorize an algebraic curve? Or use it in computations? I don't really understand what you are saying

Comment: There is a [SE site](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) for quantum computing. I bet there will be more expert for this sort of stuff.

Comment: @YuriyS I would like to store info about algebraic curve in the superposition rather than classical states. Check my example in description.

Comment: Well, it must be some kind of unitary transformation.